# How to make tasker wait for a variable to change?

Tags: javascript, java, tasker

I have a wireless button. When pressed, it sends a signal to tasker `(variable %Tap1_Action)`
I want to start a code when I press the button. How do I do this?
I tried

```
Variable set - Name: %Tap1_Action To: startCode
```

then `Wait: 5 seconds` (waiting for the press in these 5 seconds) And then starting the code with `If %Tap1_Action ~ startCode`
that somehow worked, but when I then tried to clear the variable later in the code (`Variable Clear %Tap1_Action`) and then doing that again, it immidiately set the variable to what i wanted to without me clicking on the button.

Comment: `JavaScript != Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let a profile simply watch the variable `%Tap1_Action~startCode`.
And if clearing does not work you might alter the `%Tap1_Action` variable as well as your profile only triggers a task when the variable exactly matches "startCode"